# Naughts and Crosses: Human vs Computer in Python

Tags: python, beginner, tic-tac-toe

So I am very new to programming and I am trying to pick up Python as a first language. I have programmed a simple game of naughts and crosses, but it is very wordy and there must be a simpler/quicker way of doing this! Any modifications or tips would be gratefully received.

```
from random import randint

#initialise game
board = []

for i in range(3):
    board.append(["*"]*3)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play naughts and crosses! I'll move first.\n"
print "Here's the board:\n"
list = [[' ','0','1','2'],['0','*','*','*'],['1','*','*','*'],['2','*','*','*']]

def print_list(list):
    for row in list:
        print " ".join(row)


print_list(list)
print " "

def rand_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board)-1)
def rand_col(board):
    return randint(0,len(board[0])-1)

#Computer turn initial
print "And here's my first move:\n"
comp_row = rand_row(board)
comp_col = rand_col(board)
board[comp_row][comp_col] = "O"
print_board(board)
print ""

for turn in range(20):
    #Human turn
    print "Your turn!\n"
    play_row = int(input("Choose your row: "))
    play_col = int(input("Choose your column: "))
    if (play_row < 0 or play_row > 2) or (play_col < 0 or play_col > 2):
        print "That's not even on the board!"
        print""
    elif board[play_row][play_col] == "O":
        print "Hey! That was my move!\n"
    else:
        board[play_row][play_col] = "X"
        print_board(board)
        print ""

    #Winning condition    
    if board[0] == ["X","X","X"] or board[1] == ["X","X","X"] or board[2] == ["X","X","X"]:
        print "Congratulations, you win!"
        break
    if (board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][0] == "X" and board[2][0] =="X") or (board[0][1] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][1] =="X") or (board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][2] == "X" and board[2][2] =="X"):
        print "Congratulations, you win!"
        break
    if (board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][2] == "X") or(board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][0] == "X"):
        print "Congratulations, you win!"
        break

    #Computer turn
    print"Now it's my turn again\n"
    comp_row = rand_row(board)
    comp_col = rand_col(board)
    #Conditions for override of random generator (rows) 
    if board[0][0] == "O" and board[0][1]=="O" and board[0][2] == "*":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[0][1]=="*" and board[0][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[0][1]=="O" and board[0][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[1][0] == "O" and board[1][1]=="O" and board[1][2] == "*":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[1][0] == "O" and board[1][1]=="*" and board[1][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[1][0] == "*" and board[1][1]=="O" and board[1][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[2][0] == "O" and board[2][1]=="O" and board[2][2] == "*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[2][0] == "O" and board[2][1]=="*" and board[2][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[2][0] == "*" and board[2][1]=="O" and board[2][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 0
    #condition for override (columns)
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][0] == "O" and board[2][0] =="*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][0] == "*" and board[2][0] =="O":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[1][0] == "O" and board[2][0] =="O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[0][1] == "O" and board[1][1] == "O" and board[2][1] =="*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][1] == "O" and board[1][1] == "*" and board[2][1] =="O":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][1] == "*" and board[1][1] == "O" and board[2][1] =="O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][2] == "O" and board[2][2] =="*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][2] == "*" and board[2][2] =="O":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[0][2] == "*" and board[1][2] == "O" and board[2][2] =="O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 2
    #condition for override (diagonal)
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][1] =="O" and board[2][2] == "*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][1] =="*" and board[2][2] == "O":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[1][1] =="O" and board[2][2] == "O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][1] =="O" and board[2][0] == "*":
        comp_row = 2
        comp_col = 0
    elif board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][1] =="*" and board[2][0] == "O":
        comp_row = 1
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][2] == "*" and board[1][1] =="O" and board[2][0] == "O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 2
    #if not, back to random generator
    else:
        if board[0][0] == "X" and board[0][1]=="X" and board[0][2] == "*":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[0][0] == "X" and board[0][1]=="*" and board[0][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[0][1]=="X" and board[0][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[1][0] == "X" and board[1][1]=="X" and board[1][2] == "*":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[1][0] == "X" and board[1][1]=="*" and board[1][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[1][0] == "*" and board[1][1]=="X" and board[1][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[2][0] == "X" and board[2][1]=="X" and board[2][2] == "*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[2][0] == "X" and board[2][1]=="*" and board[2][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[2][0] == "*" and board[2][1]=="X" and board[2][2] == "X": 
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 0
    #condition for override (columns)
        elif board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][0] == "X" and board[2][0] =="*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][0] == "*" and board[2][0] =="X":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[1][0] == "X" and board[2][0] =="X":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[0][1] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][1] =="*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][1] == "X" and board[1][1] == "*" and board[2][1] =="X":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][1] == "*" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][1] =="X":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][2] == "X" and board[2][2] =="*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][2] == "*" and board[2][2] =="X":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[0][2] == "*" and board[1][2] == "X" and board[2][2] =="X":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 2
    #condition for override (diagonal)
        elif board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][1] =="X" and board[2][2] == "*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 2
        elif board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][1] =="*" and board[2][2] == "X":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[1][1] =="X" and board[2][2] == "X":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][1] =="X" and board[2][0] == "*":
            comp_row = 2
            comp_col = 0
        elif board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][1] =="*" and board[2][0] == "X":
            comp_row = 1
            comp_col = 1
        elif board[0][2] == "*" and board[1][1] =="X" and board[2][0] == "X":
            comp_row = 0
            comp_col = 2

        else:
            while board[comp_row][comp_col] == "X" or board[comp_row][comp_col] == "O":
                comp_row = rand_row(board)
                comp_col = rand_col(board)
    board[comp_row][comp_col] = "O"
    print_board(board)
    print ""

    #losing condition
    if board[0] == ["O","O","O"] or board[1] == ["O","O","O"] or board[2] == ["O","O","O"]:
        print "You lose!"
        break
    if (board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][0] == "O" and board[2][0] == "O") or (board[0][1] == "O" and board[1][1] == "O" and board[2][1] == "O") or (board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][2] == "O" and board[2][2] == "O"):
        print "You lose!"
        break
    if (board[0][0] == "O" and board[1][1] == "O" and board[2][2] == "O") or(board[0][2] == "O" and board[1][1] == "O" and board[2][0] == "O"):
        print "You lose!"
        break
    if board[0][0] != "*" and board[0][1] != "*" and board[0][2] != "*" and board[1][0] != "*" and board[1][1] != "*" and board[1][2] != "*" and board[2][0] != "*" and board[2][1] != "*" and board[2][2] != "*":
        print "Game Over!"
        break
```

Comment: Useful reading: [Finite State Machines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Could potentially be used here. Also potentially consider rotational symmetry. Will look at this later when I have more time.

Comment: You could use an object oriented design for the game objects.  This would simplify the code quite a bit, and doing so allows you to isolate the implementation of the game board away from the logic for making a moving, checking the cell, etc.  I was just about to add that I'm not familiar with "Noughts and Crosses" but it looks like another name for Tic-tac-toe.  Another starting point would be repeatedly asking yourself "Where can I define a thing once and refer to vs defining it multiple times?"  That programming principle is called DRY - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that first strikes me as needing help is the repetition. For example, you have a lot of code like this:

```
    if board[0][0] == "O" and board[0][1]=="O" and board[0][2] == "*":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 2
    elif board[0][0] == "O" and board[0][1]=="*" and board[0][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 1
    elif board[0][0] == "*" and board[0][1]=="O" and board[0][2] == "O": 
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = 0
```

This could be rewritten like:

```
for i in range(3):
    if board[0][i] == "*" and board[0][(i+1)%3] == "O" and board[0][(i+2)%3] == "O":
        comp_row = 0
        comp_col = i
```

So the code for all rows, simplified to a double loop, would look like:

```
for j in range(3)
    for i in range(3):
        if board[j][i] == "*" and board[j][(i+1)%3] == "O" and board[j][(i+2)%3] == "O":
            comp_row = j
            comp_col = i
```

Similar code could be used for the columns and diagonals.

#### <Edit>

This will not quite work, as the `if...elif` will not work. This will make only the last loop go. I think the solution is to move this logic into a function, that way you can do something like:

```
def check_wins(board, p):
    for j in range(3)
        for i in range(3):
            if board[j][i] == "*" and board[j][(i+1)%3] == p and board[j][(i+2)%3] == p:
                return [j, i]
    ...
```

#### </Edit>

---

Another case of unnecessary repetition can be found in the win condition. three conditions lead to one outcome. this can be simplified to one conditional.

```
    if(
        board[0] == ["X","X","X"] or board[1] == ["X","X","X"] or board[2] == ["X","X","X"] 
    or (board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][0] == "X" and board[2][0] =="X") or (board[0][1] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][1] =="X") or (board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][2] == "X" and board[2][2] =="X") 
    or (board[0][0] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][2] == "X") or(board[0][2] == "X" and board[1][1] == "X" and board[2][0] == "X")
    ):
        print "Congratulations, you win!"
        break
```

Multi-line conditionals are explained at length in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/python-style-multiple-line-conditions-in-ifs).

---

next, let us examine the functions.

`print_board` is a function that has a useful purpose that needs to be done many times throughout the game. It is a good function.

`print_list` is used one time, right after it is defined. I think that the code could be better if it were just written inline.

`rand_row` and `rand_col' are used enough that they should be functions, although it seems to me that`randint(0,2)` would be good enough. if you change the board size, that would be the least of your worries.

Now for a method that you should add:

`has_won` would be a method that would check every way a victory could happen and tell you if a player has won. this could simplify that code.

---

lastly, `for turn in range(20):` should be `for turn in range(4):`. This will work, because 1 move at the beginning plus 4 moves of each player will fill up the board. Except for the fact that you can play on your own space. that could be fixed with:

```
elif board[play_row][play_col] == "X":
    print "You already played on that spot!\n"
```

Also, if you do an invalid move, it should let you try again.

Then you can move `"game over"` code to the end.

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful, I'll try to work through the code and make some of these amendments!